# Nodejs adding extra things at the end of a json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to parse AIS messages and append it to the end of a JSON file. I take the input from a file containing AIS messages and write it to a JSON file. My code and output(in the JSON file) are as  follows:

```
fs.watchFile(input,function(){
    console.log('New updates received');
    sentences = fs.readFileSync(input).toString().split("\n");
    sentences.forEach(function(line){
        console.log(line);
        fs.readFile(output,function(err,data){
            if(err){
                console.log("Could not read file");
            }
            else{
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(json.boats);
                //Now parse that line
                var result = parser.parse(line);
                if (result.valid == 'VALID'){
                    //Now lets make objects out of them
                    var suppValues = result.supportedValues;
                    var temp = new boat(result['aisType'],result['channel'],result['repeatInd'],result['mmsi'],result['midCountry'],result['midCountryIso'],
                    result['mmsi'],result['midCountry'],result['midCountryIso'],result['mmsiType'],result['class'], result['navStatus'],result['navStatusStr'],
                    result['rotStatus'],result['rot'],result['heading'],result['psogStatus'],result['sog'],result['cog'],result['lat'],result['lng'],
                    result['posAccuracy'],result['utcTsSec'],result['utcTsStatus']);
                    console.log("Boat = " + temp);
                        //Lets create objects out of the data that we have


                    json.boats.push(temp);
                    fs.writeFile(output,JSON.stringify(json));
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Invalid AIS Message");
                }
            }

        });
    });
});


//Boat object
function boat(aisType,channel,repeatInd,mmsi,midCountry,midCountryIso,mmsiType,class_,navStatus,navStatusStr,rotStatus,rot,heading,sogStatus,sog,cog,lat,lng,posAccuracy,utcTsSec,utcTsStatus){

    this.aisType = aisType;
    this.channel = channel;
    this.repeatInd = repeatInd;
    this.mmsi = mmsi;
    this.midCountry = midCountry;
    this.midCountryIso = midCountryIso;
    this.mmsiType = mmsiType;
    this.class_ = class_;
    this.navStatus = navStatus;
    this.navStatusStr = navStatusStr;
    this.rotStatus = rotStatus;
    this.rot = rot;
    this.heading = heading;
    this.sogStatus = sogStatus;
    this.sog = sog;
    this.cog = cog;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
    this.posAccuracy = posAccuracy;
    this.utcTsSec = utcTsSec;
    this.utcTsStatus = utcTsStatus;
}
```

JSON File:

```
{"boats":[{"aisType":3,"channel":"B","repeatInd":1,"mmsi":305885000,"midCountry":"Antigua and Barbuda","midCountryIso":"AG","mmsiType":305885000,"class_":"Antigua and Barbuda","navStatus":"AG","navStatusStr":"Vessel","rotStatus":"A","rot":1,"heading":"At anchor","sogStatus":"LEFT","sog":-3.615863355006045,"cog":35,"lng":0.2,"posAccuracy":180.8},{"aisType":3,"channel":"B","repeatInd":1,"mmsi":305885000,"midCountry":"Antigua and Barbuda","midCountryIso":"AG","mmsiType":305885000,"class_":"Antigua and Barbuda","navStatus":"AG","navStatusStr":"Vessel","rotStatus":"A","rot":1,"heading":"At anchor","sogStatus":"LEFT","sog":-3.615863355006045,"cog":35,"lng":0.2,"posAccuracy":180.8}]}":0.1,"posAccuracy":316.2}]}"sogStatus":"RIGHT","sog":null,"cog":334,"lng":0.3,"posAccuracy":280.2}]}
```

As you can see in the end of the json output there are a few things added which do not conform to the JSON syntax. Right at the end there are two curly braces which are redundant i don't understand how i am getting such an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append text to existing json file node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739630/append-text-to-existing-json-file-node-js)

Comment: Converting everything to async also dint help

Comment: try replacing  `writeFile` with `writeFileSync` for now to see if it works

Comment: Too much was wrong with that code, even though it was synchronous the IO overhead was just too much(probably) when I removed the IO operation inside the loop to outside of it and made everything synchronous and also took the write operation out of the loop everything now works well.